# SQL Invalid Column error on Dynamic Query

Tags: sql-server, dynamicquery

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(MaxDate)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MaxDate FROM CustPeriodTable) AS MaxDates

SET @DynamicPivotQuery =

N'SELECT ' + @ColumnName + ' AS Test, min(rn)
FROM CustPeriodTable '

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

I'm getting an invalid column name error for every entry in @ColumnName. I'm in the process of setting up a more complicated query that will involve a pivot but I'm trying to get this chunk working first. Can anyone point out where this problem might be coming from?

Comment: `select [2014-01-24] as test`? you have fields named with dates?

Comment: Yes, each column will have a date and then data for those dates. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: well, it's one thing to produce a pivot table where those columns are built on-the-fly. it's another to have an actual table with those field names. dynamic field names are almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these types of issues you need to look at what the dynamic query is. Instead of executing it just select it.

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(MaxDate)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MaxDate FROM CustPeriodTable) AS MaxDates

SET @DynamicPivotQuery =

N'SELECT ' + @ColumnName + ' AS Test, min(rn)
FROM CustPeriodTable '

SELECT @DynamicPivotQuery

-- EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

From here you should be able to determine what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks this at least helped me visualize what was going on I didn't know you could do this, thanks!

Comment: @user41829 No problem. It will definitely help when you need to figure out what a variable is getting set too when doing dynamic sql. I've had very large queries where I put a bunch of checkpoints that would just print what the variables currently were.

Comment: Other option would be using coalesce